# Почему связи между таблицами не работают [FeathersJS -sequelize]?

Tags: mysql, node.js, связывание-данных, sequelize.js, feathersjs

- фреймворк [Feathers](https://feathersjs.com) ^2.2.3
- ORM [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) (feathers-sequelize ^2.3.2)
- база данных MySQL
- 2 таблицы между которыми нужно организовать связь

в файле `category.model.js` описываю связь:

```
category.associate = function (models) {
    models.category.belongsTo(models.category_translate, {
      foreignKey: 'id',
      constraints: false,
      targetKey: 'category_id',
      as: 'translate'
    });
  };
```

Теперь если обращаться по адресу `localhost:3030/category` то выводиться результат данного запроса:

```
SELECT `id`, `icon`, `parent` FROM `category` AS `category` LIMIT 10;
```

Пробовал так `localhost:3030/category?$select[]=translate`, чтобы получить доступ ко полям со связанной таблицы, но возникла ошибка.

Что делаю не так?

Как получить доступ к данным с другой таблице по связи из текущей модели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что нужно было сделать `hook`, которые включил бы связь к запросам. Я создал `translateHook.js`

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return function categoryTranslate (hook) {
    const AssociatedModel = hook.app.services['category-translate'].Model;

    hook.params.sequelize = {
       include: [{
        model: AssociatedModel,
        as: 'translate',
        query: {
          $limit: 1,
          $select: ['country_icon']
        },
        where: {
            lang: hook.params.query['$language']
        }
        }]
    };
    delete hook.params.query['$language'];

    return Promise.resolve(hook);
  };
};
```

источник [тут](https://weburoki.pro/model-relation-feathers-feathers).